# Closing stage on key release

Tags: java, javafx, keylistener, hotkeys

I have created a VBox in javafx that comes like a pop up on my application based on hot key combination alt + j. Now all I want to do is close the VBox when I release the key combination alt + j. This is my piece of code

```
final Stage dialog = new Stage();
EventHandler handler = new EventHandler<KeyEvent>()
{
    public void handle( KeyEvent event )
    {
        if ( event.isAltDown() && event.getCode() == KeyCode.J )
        {
            dialog.initStyle( StageStyle.UNDECORATED );
            // dialog.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            VBox dialogVbox = new VBox( 25 );
            dialogVbox.getChildren().add( new Text( "ABC" ) );
            Scene dialogScene = new Scene( dialogVbox, 300, 200 );
            dialog.setScene( dialogScene );
            dialog.show();
        }
        else if ( KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED.equals( eventRel.isAltDown() && eventRel.getCode() == KeyCode.J ) )
        {
            dialog.hide();
        }
    }
};

scene.addEventHandler( KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, handler );
```

But this does not close as expected.
Please guide me with the VBox close on key release

As per the comment I also created a separate handler for key release  : 
That did not close the vBox

```
EventHandler handlerRel = new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        public void handle(KeyEvent eventRel) {
        //event.consume();


             if(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED.equals(eventRel.isAltDown() && eventRel.getCode() == KeyCode.J))
                {
                    System.out.println("Inside released");
                    dialog.hide();
                }


            }};         


    scene.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, handlerRel);
```

Thanks

Comment: You only added the event handler to `KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED` you also have to add it (or create a separate one for `KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED`.

Comment: I did that just see the edited code Thanks

Comment: That `if` in the second handler looks off. I think you are doing a `equals` check against the result of the button check there. Meaning: Shouldn't the `if` condition be the same as in the first handler?

Comment: That is a check for key release so when I release the key my vBox should close.

Comment: This handler is only executed on release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attaching the two handlers to the same scene. However, once the 2nd scene is created, namely dialogScene, it becomes active and is the scene that is receiving events. Therefore, the fix for your solution is to attach the KEY_RELEASED event handler to dialogScene and not the original scene.

```
                dialogScene.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, event -> {
                    if (event.isAltDown() && event.getCode() == KeyCode.J )
                    {
                        dialog.hide();
                    }
                });
```